# Cannot assign to property: 'value' is a get-only property RxSwift -

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I want to assign a  value to an BehaviorRelay in RxSwift - RxCocoa. But I get this error message: "Cannot assign to property: 'value' is a get-only property".

Thats my code: 
private var todos = BehaviorRelay<[MainToDoData]>(value: [])
todos.value = todosVM.data

Comment: Don't ever make a `BehaviorRelay` a `var`. It should be a `let`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use **accept**:

```
todos.accept(todosVM.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Jump to Definition in `BehaviorRelay`

You can see this:

```
/// Accepts `event` and emits it to subscribers    
public func accept(_ event: Element)

/// Current value of behavior subject
public var value: Element { get }
```

`value` is a get value.

use `accept(_ event: Element)` like `todos.accept(todosVM.data)`